# Using Pre-trained Transformer Model to Expand Short Sentences to Long Sentences

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, pre-trained-model

I need to build a model that can expand multiple short sentences to multiple long sentences. I was thinking to use a pre-trained Transformer model to do this just like when we want to do a paragraph or text summarization except, in this case, I switched the output and input values. I tried this using `t5-base`, ran it on Google Colab, and using really minimum data like 10 rows of data, the idea was to see whether it works or not regardless of the output. But I always got errors like below:

> RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 502.00 MiB (GPU 0;
> 11.17 GiB total capacity; 10.29 GiB already allocated; 237.81 MiB free; 10.49 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)

I interpret this error as I did something wrong or my idea did not work. Is there anyone who can suggest how to do this?

Please advise

Comment: The error shows your model doesn't fit in GPU memory, try a smaller variant.

Comment: @meti I reduce the batch size and it solves the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I reduce the batch size and it solves the problem.